# Context.xml not coming to WAR on mvn clean install

Tags: java, xml, eclipse, maven

i am working on maven project (servlet). i made a context.xml and put it under :
 **/ovmgmt/target/m2e-wtp/web-resources/META-INF**

When i build the project(using mvn clean install) context.html gets deleted and does not come into my WAR. 
If i build the project using mvn install only then it stays.

I have gone through much of the questions at stack overflow and some other sites also but nothing helps.

I have no resource- ref in my web.xml, is it causing the problem.

Comment: And why are you putting the file in a target directory rather than the widely documented correct folders such as src/main/resources or src/main/webapp ?

Comment: The `clean` goal will delete `target` folder contents. Put your resources into appropriate folders.

Comment: @Gimby IF i put the context.xml in src/main/resources then it is not coming into the war. It is supposed to come in META-INF but not coming.

Comment: when i put it under src/main/webapp then also it doesn't come in META-INF on build.

Comment: It will if you put it in src/main/webapp/META-INF/context.xml.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the eventual answer: don't put the file in a target folder, put it in the proper source folder as defined by the Maven documentation. Maven web modules have a folder src/main/webapp for web resources, so a web resource META-INF/context.xml must be saved as src/main/webapp/META-INF/context.xml.

Just to complete the picture: there is also a folder src/main/resources. The resources you put there will be packaged into the WEB-INF/classes folder.

src/main/webapp -> web resources

src/main/resources -> classpath resources